# How find in bytecodes part of the code?

Tags: solidity, web3js, bytecode

If with this code I can find the signature of a function in a solidity contract:

```
const hash = Web3.utils.sha3(word).slice(0, 10).substring(2);
```

How could I find another one?

ex:

```
assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The function's signature are special because they are used by the function dispatcher. Other parts of the code don't behave like that.

Comment: @Ismael Have a deep understanding of how solidity is transformed into bytes

Comment: If you know C++ you can read the solidity compiler here https://github.com/ethereum/solidity. It translates the high level solidity language into EVM bytecode sequences.